# Pokemon GO crashes after I tap items or try to catch a Pokemon

Tags: pokemon-go

It appears that ever since the update to 0.33.0 I can't catch any Pokemon. When I tap on a wild Pokemon, the game crashes. 
It also crashes when I try to open 'Items'.

In the previous version everything worked fine.

I'm using Huawei P6, 4.4.2
It appears that other P6 users also have this problem.

Comment: Have you tried uninstalling the app and reinstalling?

Comment: I have tried that a few times already, didn't work.

Comment: I have the exakt same issue in the laste version of the game (0.51.0). Not sure how and when it started.

Comment: I'm having the same issi in v 0.51.0 of the game!! Anyone solved this yet?

Answer (score 0):

Without a doubt the new pokemon go updates have brought with them a kit of bugs and glitches.
My brother had this issue and he fixed it by cleaning the app cache and then deactivating the AR mode while catching a pokemon.
Try this and let us know!

Comment: I cleaned the cache, and I always have AR off, but the problem is still there :(
Thanks for the answer though!

Comment: Okay. Well I gonna suggest another solution hope this works. Clean cache and uninstall the app, then in another phone that has never have pokemon go installed, install the app and log in then catch a pokemon. After that  go back to your phone and install the app log in and try catching a pokemon. Try this and let me know.